What causes Cannot find module '~/pages/index.vue' or its corresponding type declarations. ts(2307) error while using router.options.ts?
see sample image here
I have a nuxt 3 project and I would like to use custom routing with it. I followed nuxt documentation on custom routing and added a folder named 'app' and inside I created router.options.ts file. Upon creating custom routes I get this error ts(2307) and does not have any clue on what causes the error.
I've read Nuxt documentation about custom routing but it does not say anything regarding this error or what I need to do beforehand. I am not sure if I miss anything during set up can anyone help?
I would want to know what causes the error and the steps on how to remove it.

Just remove .nuxt, restart the IDE and nuxt dev server

@typed-sigterm it didn't work. I still have the error any other ideas?

Wait, Nuxt can automatically process what you're trying doing. You don't need to write router.option.ts
